# ModelSim: Intel On-Chip Flash IP: Error: (vsim-3033) Instantiation of 'altera_onchip_flash_block' failed

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am getting this vsim error when I'm trying to use an Intel On-Chip Flash IP generated by Quartus. There's an altera_onchip_flash_block.v file in the submodules/rtl folder but it's only hex numbers in it so it's not compilable by ModelSim.

```
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /ufm_testbench/ufm_inst/flash/onchip_flash_0 File: ../../FFB900_UFM/verilog/altera_onchip_flash.v Line: 309
#         Searched libraries:
(all my libraries)
```

The altera_onchip_flash_block gets instantiated in the altera_onchip_flash.v as seen above.
When I'm only compiling the IP it's working but when I'm using it from my Top-Level testbench I always get this error. I am using VHDL in all my files, except the verilog files generated by quartus.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you are using a MAX 10 FPGA?

Comment: @Bananenkönig Yes I'm using MAX 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already realized, this is a precompiled IP-Core. Normally these precompiled IP-Cores come with files for simulation.

[This pdf](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_ufm.pdf) includes a step-by-step tutorial to instantiate the IP-Core and generate simulation files with Quartus (on page 12 of 36 or section 4-2).

Comment: Thank you. I did all these steps before. I want to use the IP-Core within a vhdl testbench thats generated by a tool made by my company.

Comment: So what did you get from step 6?

Comment: I didn't use step 6 because as I said I already have a testbench in which I want to use the IP core.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to generate the testbench for the IP Core, which further can be used to instantiate in your actual testbench.

Comment: I don't really know why but that seems to work, at least for compilation. I need to check functionality now. Thank you!

Comment: Those IP-Cores come precompiled. After parametrizing the testbench for those parameters must be generated by Quartus, because the testbench will change if you change the parameter of the IP-Core. This testbench can now be employed in your actual testbench for simulating. This will be just behavioural code and not synthesizable, as it isn't needed for simulating.